# Is there a created() for vuex actions to auto dispatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have an action within vuex that I would like to auto dispatch within vuex itself rather than a component.

I have created a notification bar that changes through different notifications which is on multiple pages. Rather than the notifications start from the beginning when I switch page I have created a store to set which notification to show.

I would like to dispatch the rotate function in the vuex store from within vuex rather than from within a component

*Please note: I'm using Nuxt*

**VUEX State: store/notifications.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
    section: 0,
    notifications: [
        'notification 1',
        'notification 2',
        'notification 3'
    ]
})

export const mutations = {
    INC_SECTION(state) {
        state.section ++
    },
    RESET_SECTION(state) {
        state.section = 0
    }
}

export const actions = {
    rotate({commit, dispatch, state}) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                
                let total = state.notifications.length -1
    
                if (state.section === total) {
                    commit('RESET_SECTION')
                }
                else {
                    commit('INC_SECTION')
                }
                dispatch('rotate')
    
            }, 3500)
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

**VUE JS Component:**

```html
<template>
  <section class="notifications">
    <template v-for="(notification, i) in notifications" >
      <p v-if="$store.state.notifications.section === i" :key="i">{{notification}}</p>
    </template>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { notifications: [] }
  },
  computed: {
    setData() {
      this.notifications = this.$store.state.notifications.notifications
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.setData
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of much cleaner ways you can do this.

First of all if you are using Nuxt, then, IMO you should be using its awesome feature of [middlewares](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware) for dispatching actions (your use case of not keeping it, on the component level).

Secondly, Vuex provides us `mapGetters` functionality which makes the state properties available in the components while keeping them reactive, at the same time, too.

So, you can go with the following:

**Vuex Store:**

```
export const state = () => ({
  section: 0,
  notifications: ["notification 1", "notification 2", "notification 3"]
});

export const mutations = {
  INC_SECTION(state) {
    state.section++;
  },
  RESET_SECTION(state) {
    state.section = 0;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  rotate({ commit, dispatch, state }) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let total = state.notifications.length - 1;
      if (state.section === total) {
        commit("RESET_SECTION");
      } else {
        commit("INC_SECTION");
      }
      dispatch("rotate");
    }, 3500);
  }
};

export const getters = {
  notifications(state) {
    return state.notifications;
  },
  section(state) {
    return state.section;
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
};
```

**Vue Component:**

```
<template>
  <section class="notifications">
    <template v-for="(notification, i) in notifications">
      <p v-if="section === i" :key="i">{{ notification }}</p>
    </template>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["notifications", "section"])
  }
};
</script>
```

**Middleware**

```
export default function({ store }) {
  store.dispatch("rotate");
}
```

depending on your use case, you can keep this middleware global (attached to routes), or attached to a specific layout.

here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yjw28pkpjz) example. hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to help. This only works when I change route, and it triggers it each time I change route so I have the same issue as before.

Is there any way to trigger the middleware on initial site load only?

Comment: To solve this I have created a plugin instead of the middleware called onload.js:

`export default function ({ app, store }) {
    app.router.onReady(() => store.dispatch("rotate"))
  }`

and updated nuxt.config.js

`plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/onLoad.js', ssr: false}
  ]`