# self dispatch action within nuxt vuex module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

Following on from this question [Is there a created() for vuex actions to auto dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317639/is-there-a-created-for-vuex-actions-to-auto-dispatch/)

I was able to self dispatch the action, though this removed the reactive capabilities when accessing the state from a component.

Is the a way to do this without losing reactivity? I'm unable to dispatch it form a component since it triggers a timeout function multiple times.

Comment: You can remove the Java tag and put javascript tag instead

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54322914/6333527

Comment: Solved by Waleed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317639/is-there-a-created-for-vuex-actions-to-auto-dispatch/54322914#54322914